# Does Logback require Groovy in classpath ? Using logback.xml and not logback.gorovy for configuration

Tags: java, logback, slf4j

I couldn't to see anything related in the documentation but have received the following exception

```
Failed to instantiate [ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext]
Reported exception:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/groovy/control/CompilationFailedException
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
```

Comment: when do you get this exception ? Is there any other piece of  code that needs access to groovy jar ? Try including the complete stack trace.

Comment: Please also include your logback.xml file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, logback does **not** require Groovy. However, your `logback.xml` file is probably invoking `GEventEvaluator` which is Groovy based.

Comment: why depend on groovy or janino here? Surely jdk should have decent scripting support for java /javascript ?